# JAVA, SQL exception while retrieving a value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception, bigint

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1, and glassfish 3.1, the DB is MySql.

There is a table in the database called `HotelNames`, i need to write a SQL and pass the Hotel name to get its hotel ID. I get an exception which i am unable to solve.

```
    @Override
public int GetHotelID(String hotellName) {
   Query query  = em.createNativeQuery("select ID from HotelNames where hotName ='"+ hotellName+"'");
    String hotelID =  (String) query.getSingleResult();

    return Integer.parseInt(hotelID );
}
```

The exception i get points to the SQL i wrote in the above code

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

MySQL create table looks like;

```
CREATE TABLE HotelNames (`ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `hotName` VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

I think its because of the `BIGINT` in the SQL and `int` in the code that's causing this, but  i am unable to solve this.

Comment: The error is not in the return, its the line above. But, why do you try to parse a BigInt to String and then to Int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns an `BigInteger`. So you can get an int like that:

```
        return ((BigInteger)  query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to do something like this

```
Number hotelID =  (Number) query.getSingleResult();
return hotelID.intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.String 
- You are trying to convert the ID to string, which is BigInteger..
See String hotelID =  (String) query.getSingleResult();

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger bg = new BigInteger();
bg = query.getSingleResult();
String hotelId = bg.toString();
```

I hope this explains more.....you can also do it in one line if you wish to...